# ruby 1.9.2 + pcap on Mac OS X

Tags: ruby, macos, pcap

Has anyone been able to successfully use a pcap library for Ruby 1.9.2 (via rvm) on Mac OS X 10.6?

I have tried pcaprub and it seems to not behave well on Mac OS X and the pcap gem isn't compatible with ruby 1.9.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's definitely some problems building the native extension stuff for the pcap gem on ruby 1.9.2 (I'm on patch 180). Mostly you can get it working by changing RUBYSTR(foo)->ptr to RUBYSTR_PTR(foo) -- that's fairly easy to macro away when you see gcc complaining.

The real problem for me is that it's blocking after the initial call in pcap_loop. I initially was able to get it to do the right thing, but it doesn't want to use the correct timeout. If I can get it working right, I'll definitely be pushing changes upstream.

Edit: see my comments [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5479229/ruby-1-9-2-and-pcap-gem-compiling-error/5479537#5479537) to get it building on 10.6.

Edit2: I've forked ruby-pcap and got it working on ruby 1.9.2 @ patch 180 on Mac OS X 10.6.7; I will be submitting a pull request to the gem shortly. In the meantime, you can get it [here](https://github.com/tjarratt/ruby-pcap)